# GIMP: 'move layer' stops working

Tags: gimp, layers

I'm having intermittent problems with GIMP, where the 'move layer' command suddenly stops working. The mouse pointer changes to the one below:

[image: cursor]

When I make an explicit selection, e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on a layer, then MOVE works again. But normally I can move whole layers without any selection (e.g. Select/None or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). This stops working out of the blue and I have no idea why.

It behaves very much like when you press ALT in MOVE mode. Pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> with a selection allows you to move the selection around, as opposed to move the layer. Pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> without a selection gives the same cursor as above, which is perfectly normal. Somehow when my problem starts, it looks as if ALT-mode is stuck and I can't get out.

Note I am a rather seasoned GIMP user and I use keyboard commands a lot, perhaps I switch too fast between commands, but I haven't been able to consistently reproduce it yet. Happens once every few hours or so. Only solution I found so far is to quit GIMP and restart. Other functions continue to work, I can still save etc (luckily).

I'm using GIMP 2.8.2 on Windows.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I ran into this because I used <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between two GIMP windows.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Looks like your move tool is in 'Move selection' mode. Check the Move setting in the tool options (this image is from the docs and shows Move layer mode):

[image: GIMP Move tool options]

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key toggles to the 'Move selection' mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> does the same for 'Move path'), and is supposed to switch back to 'Move layer' once you let go of the key. If you manage to steal the input focus from the canvas while in this mode, then the tool may remain in 'Move selection' mode.

See the following bug report for an example: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=732160

So to answer the question and solve the problem, you should set this back to 'Move layer'.

However, for me in GIMP 2.8.14 the cursor stays like this only until I actually try to use the tool again; it switches back to 'Move layer' mode automatically then.

Comment: OMG, thank you for this! It was driving me crazy!

Comment: I know you're not supposed to just say thanks but you're a lifesaver!

Comment: I was flipping tables.

Comment: Gimp is just so awful when its comes to UI

Comment: @JamieHutber we're always open to suggestions, but please make them read like you have invested more than five minutes of your time into them :)

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher this could be a textbook example of a 'modal error' (see Jef Raskin Humane Interface).  This is terrible UI because  A) there's no indication that the Move tool has multiple modes, and whatever indicators you use to indicate the current mode are not apparent.  B) it layers an additional 'submode' upon the additional 'major mode' regime of the 'selected tool' (this idea of submodes should be scrapped) C) can easily be activated by accident by some key combo, effect is to 'disable GIMP' D)   submode selection survives GIMP restart.

Comment: The tool options are part of the default UI, the mode is part of the tool cursor, and a reliable way to get it stuck has not been pointed out yet.

Comment: In Mac - no matter what option I choose - I still can't move the layer. It shows firbidden icon always.

Comment: I just got Gimp 2.8.22 stuck with these symptoms, and had to Google "why does gimp show a no entry sign when I try to move a layer". Thankfully, I found this. Gimp should have shown a message advising how to fix my problem. You may ask "how could it know my problem?".  Easily, I think. It must have a condition saying the move operation is invalid in the current state. Nevertheless, the user is trying it. So make a list of goals the user might have been trying to achieve, and ask whether any of them was intended. If the user replies yes, give advice. I've done this in UI's that I've written.

Comment: Someone delete this feature!

Comment: But, but... how could the setting have changed? I may have pressed the keyboard, but I'm confident I didn't click the mouse on the button! :D I went nuts and started resetting things to default. LOL

Comment: Maybe something similar to what this merge request is addressing for the selection tools: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/merge_requests/844. You may have used a modifier key to temporarily switch to moving a selection or a path, and then the key release was not recognized anymore.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Can I alter the operation mode with the keyboard (without emulating a mouse!), either via the menus or by tying a command to a key combination? I spent some time unsuccessfully trying to find a way to do that! Or should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 9):

Not exactly an answer but related. To view `Toolbox Options` on mac, which can be a bit tricky to find, is one of the 'tab' next to layers and can be activated from `Windows > toolbox Options - brushes`

[image]

Comment: FYI, on Windows at least, you can also double click on a tool (e.g. the move tool) to activate/open the Tool Options for that tool.

Comment: If you have the panel open, you can find it in selection menu.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem where I couldn't move the layer.  I tried setting tool options appropriately and even resetting the tool options.  It turned out I had a layer mask on all my my layers so when I selected a layer it was selecting the mask instead of the image.  I could see the boundary moving, but the image was stationary.

Selecting the image after selecting the layer solved this issue for me.

Comment: Had the same problem ("I had a layer mask on all my my layers"), that's because I clicked the right logo in the layers panel, instead of the left one... tricky Gimp!!

Comment: Can you clarify “Selecting the image after selecting the layer”?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar problem (for text boxes) where the Move tool would not change focus (ie: dotted outline changes to the text box I click on. Turns out I had the Layers windows in 'Paths' mode. When I switched back to Layers, the problem was 'fixed'.

Comment: Uh? What to you mean by *Layers windows in 'Paths' mode*?