# GIMP cant move layer

Tags: gimp, layers

This is a common issue but none of the previous posts had the same thing, and none of the fixes worked.
As the title said, I cant move the layers up and down the layer stack, and when I add a new player it isn't named "Layer" but rather "final" which is rather odd, might have something to do with it.

Comment: The name of the new layer is saved in the new layer dialog, so new layers are by default named by the mast name you entered. What previous posts did you try?

Comment: I have read these two main ones, and thing that suggested the same thing
https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Can-t-move-layers
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/44508/gimp-move-layer-stops-working

I also found that i can move the layers from the layers drop down up top, i just cant drag them.

Answer (score 1):

Okay figured it out!
This wasn't gimp's fault at all!
This was the fault of gimp not being able to detect the dropping of the layer, due to other application's interference.
Invisible full screen applications tend to mess things like this up, like overlays or some services, common culprits include skype, overwolf (this was my case) and other similar programs which use invisible fullscreen windows to do their magic.

Comment: This also happens to me when I use screen recording software. Note that if you can't click and drag the layer because of some other software running, it is still possible to move the layers up or down the stack using the arrow buttons in the layers panel.